# Unserialize WP_Options options programatically?

Tags: javascript

I need to programatically unserialize the wp_options options. I'm creating a Java App to change database information, such as some options on wp_options, so that I won't need to access the panel to do it.

How can I unserialize options like

```
   a:4:{i:0;s:5:"posts";i:1;s:5:"pages";i:2;s:4:"tags";i:3;s:10:"categories";}
```

or

```
    a:1:{s:12:"_multiwidget";i:1;}
```

Change them and re-serialize to the database?

Thanks

Comment: So you are asking how to [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) PHP data in Java and you tag the question with `javascript`. Which one is it in the end?

Comment: Note that Java and javascript are completely unrelated programming languages

Comment: instead of recreating the "unserialize" function of PHP, I recommand you to send data to a PHP code which would do this work. You can send a HTTP request from Java to PHP with this : https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

The `get_option` and `update_option` functions in PHP automatically handle serialization/unserialization for you:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

If you need to interface with these functions using JavaScript (assuming JavaScript and not Java, as others have pointed out) you could register an AJAX endpoint that calls these functions for you that you can interface with via JavaScript on the front-end:

https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins